# Is it a good idea to use shouldComponentUpdate for all components in my app?

Tags: reactjs

LoDash has wonderfull [method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.1#isEqual) `_.isEqual`. Is it a good idea to use:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(newProps, newState) {
  return !_.isEqual(newsProps, this.props) || !_.isEqual(newState, this.state);
}
```

for all components in my app? If isn't, why?

Comment: It's not a good idea. There is no need for this - a component update will execute the render() method and change the virtual DOM, real costly updates on the real DOM are handled by React itself. This is only useful for corner cases where render() takes too much time.

Comment: It would be cool to understand is `render` method working faster then `shouldComponentUpdate` or not in specific case. Maybe there's a way for that?

Comment: You could also use the [PureRenderMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) or the more modern [PureComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) which essentially do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, no. Although a component may be re-rendering, that doesn't necessarily mean that there will be an update to the DOM. React does some comparison behind the scenes, so it only updates the DOM when the DOM actually needs to change (More info on this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)).

Additionally, LoDash's `isEqual` method does a *deep compare* this means that it goes through an object or array (or whatever it is given) and checks compares property of every child and every child's child (and so on) of that element to the child of the other value. For small objects, this doesn't take long, but it can get *extremely* time consuming when your objects get large.

Even if you are passing the `isEqual` method something that is quick to compare, there's probably a more efficient method of handling this. Typically, the render method of a component will only take a couple of ms, and, as mentioned, the DOM will only update if something is actually different. If you have an abnormally expensive render method, you may want to use a [Pure Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). Pure components do a shallow props comparison that doesn't recursive into each of an objects children. That way, it can skip the render function if the props *look* the same. Do note that if you have nested properties in the props, a pure component won't catch them, and your component won't rerender.

Typically, you would only want to use `shouldComponentUpdate` if you want to delay the rendering until props contain certain values (think `this.props.someValue && this.props.someOtherValue`), this is useful if you are fetching data from a server and you want to wait until you have it all to render a component. Another time when you may want to use `shouldComponentUpdate` is when you are rendering a list of items. If one of the children change and the entire list needs to rerender, you can simulate a pure component by checking the props necessary to render and skip the rendering otherwise. There *are* other use cases, but they are usually unique, and you'll probably know when you should use `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Finally, using `shouldComponentUpdate` is typically a performance optimization. If your react app isn't suffering performance issues, you probably don't need to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason to use `shouldComponentUpdate` is when you have both a really slow `render` method AND are very frequently setting 'new' state or props that do not actually change the outcome of your render.

For most apps, this is not the case. So in general **no**, you are wasting time by doing this